# How to shake off duplicate links while parsing web-data?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've written some script in vba to parse the links leading to the next page from a torrent site. My script is able to scrape them. However, the issue I'm facing is that couple of duplicate links coming along in the result. My question is whether there is any technique with which I can parse only the unique links?

```
Sub TorrentData()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://yts.ag/browse-movies", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("tsc_pagination")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(post, "page") > 0 Then
           x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.href
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```

Partial picture of the scraped links:

[image]

Be sure to check the link before proceeding:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/647x3m65u90a1bu/Description1.txt?dl=0"

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is you can add the links to a dictionary. Before getting the output, check if they exist or not.

Comment: Thanks Tehscript for your comment. I'm not that familiar with dictionary usage. I did find a workaround but that is not what I want. Gonna paste a link in my post.

Comment: Hi Tehscript, maintaining your suggestion I tried to use dictionary in my script and it is giving me perfect results. However the problem is I can't rearrange my script to give a better look. Here is a link FYC : "https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3668q9da9u8qr4/Rmoving%20duplicates%20with%20dictionary%20in%20vba..txt?dl=0"

Comment: You don't have to loop two times. When you check if it exits or not in dictionary, you can both add the link to dictionary and write it to cell at the same time.

Comment: This is the best I could think of  from my shallow knowledge "https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3668q9da9u8qr4/Rmoving%20duplicates%20with%20dictionary%20in%20vba..txt?dl=0"

Comment: No, not like that. I can send it as an answer when I'm home.

Comment: Thanks Tehscript. Eagerly waiting for that very moment.

Comment: The site "https://yts.ag/browse-movies" is not responding?

Comment: There is an inverted comma coming along with that link. Try here: "https://yts.ag/browse-movies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make the site work. Anyways, the proper way to use dictionary to eliminate duplicates and write to cells inside the same loop should look something like this:

```
For Each Post In html.getElementsByClassName("tsc_pagination")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(Post.href, "page") > 0 Then
        If Not dict.Exists(Post.href) Then
            dict.Add Post.href, "whatever information you would like to store"
            x = x + 1
            Cells(x, 1) = Post.href
        End If
    End If
Next Post
```

Comment: Thanks Tehscript. It works as you said. Btw, is it necessary to keep this part ", "whatever information you would like to store"". I tried to take out but was having error. Thanks again.

Comment: Hehe. A dictionary consists of a key and a value. To demonstrate `dict = {"numberofapples":30,"yourname":"SMth80","yourparsedwebsite":"https://yts.ag/browse-movies"}`. In the above example, your key holds `post.href` and you can assign a value to this key. It might be `x`, it might be another information from the website related to `post.href`, or you can set it to any constant value like `1`, `"Hello"`, or `"whatever information you would like to store"`.

Comment: As long as you set it to something it is fine because a key has to have a value. The question is, are you going to use this value later on? For the time being, the part that interests you is the `Key`, not the `Value`. But later on your code, you might want to extract `Value` from the corresponding `Key`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Hi Tehscript! In your spare time, please follow the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362363/how-to-get-all-the-links-leading-to-the-next-page"